# How to get user id using jwt token

Tags: node.js, jwt, access-token, express-jwt

I tried to get user id from a JWT token. I got a JWT token and sucessfully verified it, but it doesn't return an id.

When I decode the JWT:

```js
const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'));  
var userId = decoded.id  
console.log(decoded)
```

I got this output:

```
{ iat: 1561463667 }
```

But I excepted this output:

```
id :"*****************"
```

How do I get the user id from the token?

Comment: Show how you have done `jwt.sign`

Comment: how do you encode your jwt?

Comment: Just console `decode` and share what you got in that.

Comment: I got only same out put { iat: 1561463667 }

Comment: That would imply that your token has no other data.. it's missing the `id` field in any case. Your code isn't wrong, your token is.

Comment: @SachinShah Thx for the hint!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the whole output is `{ iat: 1561463667 }`, it means, that no extra payload/claims were added when the token was signed.
The [jsonwebtoken package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) usually adds [`iat` (issuedAt](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.6), the time when the token was issued) as a default claim.

In simple words: you can only decode claims, that were added before.

To add more claims, try this code (when you're in control of the code which issues the token):

```
let payload = { "id" : "1"};
let token = jwt.sign( payload,'secret',  { noTimestamp:true, expiresIn: '1h' });
```

Here I added an [expiry time (`exp`)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4), and set the option `noTimestamp` to suppress the automatically added `iat` claim.

The result looks like this:

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "exp": 1561471747
}
```

and the token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjEiLCJleHAiOjE1NjE0NzI0MzV9.jmKyITRoxLl0fy0-rrwgPOA_iRgGQu8W4Cc6dPupOMA
```

Then you can get the id as you have already shown in your question:

```
const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "your secret or key");  
var userId = decoded.id  
console.log(userId)
```

You can also paste the above shown JWT or your token into the https://jwt.io debugger, to inspect the token and see the structure and the actual claim names. Maybe there's no `id`, but a `userId` or similar, or a [`sub`claim](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.2), which is a registerd claim name to be used to identify the principal:

> The "sub" (subject) claim identifies the principal that is the
> subject of the JWT.

It might also happen, that the token contains nested objects, e.g.:

```
{
  "user_data": 
    {
      "user_id": "1",
      "user_name: "superuser"
    },
 "exp": 1561471747
}
```

then you get the user_id this way:

```
const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "your secret or key");  
var userId = decoded.user_data.user_id  
console.log(userId)
```

Comment: In this, you have skip token expiry time.

Comment: of course `exp`should be added, but that's not the point of the question here.

Comment: I think that is the point of the question, Hear he got expiry time when he used `decode.id`. He got expiry time value when expected output is user's id.

Comment: no, he didn't get expiry time, he got, as I explained, the iat (issued at) time. That's when the token was signed. And, as I said, the framework adds this automatically. I added the code for expiryTime in my answer.